# Having Monday as the first day of the week

Tags: locale

My locale setting for LC_TIME is set to Swedish but despite this `cal` displays Sunday instead of Monday as the first day of the week. Any clues?

```
$ locale
LANG=sv_SE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

$ grep first_weekday /usr/share/i18n/locales/sv_SE
first_weekday 2

$ cal
   November 2012      
sö må ti on to fr lö  
             1  2  3  
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10  
11 12 13 14 15 16 17  
18 19 20 21 22 23 24  
25 26 27 28 29 30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cal` can not change the start of the week.

You could use `ncal` which respects those locale settings. If you do not like the layout use `ncal -C` to switch to the classical `cal` layout.

Comment: Added `alias cal="ncal -C"` to ~/.bashrc

Comment: This isn't true anymore `cal` from util-linux now respects your locae.